# QNetworkAccessManager without finished signal

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtnetwork

I want to request and response directly instead of using `connect(..,SLOT(finished()),..,SLOT())`

Comment: Sure. Help me!, I want to build app  has architect the same 3-tires/MVC

Comment: response directly. Right.

Comment: Right. Please  post an answer such as code example or document with code . Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `QEventLoop` so that the application waits and can handle other events at the same time.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://api.github.com/events")));
    loop.exec();

    qDebug()<<reply->readAll();

    delete reply;
    delete manager;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am checking now

Comment: Ok, I kinda imagined that :)