# QNetworkReply::RemoteHostClosedError

Tags: qt, github-api, qtnetwork

I was learning the Github API and wanted to create an Issue on github by Qt.

But, when I submit my Issue, the "Debug Console" said

```
QNetworkReply::RemoteHostClosedError
```

(I catched error).

I don't know why, please help me!

[Code on Github](https://github.com/MoyuSteve/Comment):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QString id = ui->ID_Send->text();
    QJsonObject JJ;
    QJsonDocument jd;
    JJ["title"] = ui->Title->text();
    JJ["body"] = ui->Comment->toPlainText();
    QHttpMultiPart *part = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
    QHttpPart info;
    info.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("text/json"));
    jd.setObject(JJ);
    info.setBody(jd.toJson());
    part->append(info);

    QNetworkRequest request;
    qDebug()<<"https://api.github.com/repos/MoyuSteve/Comment/issues?client_id="+
              client_id+"&client_secret="+client_secret;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("https://api.github.com/repos/MoyuSteve/Comment/issues?client_id="+
                        client_id+"&client_secret="+client_secret));
    QNetworkReply* reply = manager->post(request,part);
    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply, this] () {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            ui->status->setText("ok");
        } else {
            ui->status->setText("failed");
            qDebug()<<reply->error();
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh,And sometimes it is QNetworkReply::ContentNotFoundError.

Comment: Please read [ask] and review the [tour]. Show your code as text. and provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You can take example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50541714/6309) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49869286/6309).

Compared to your code, it sets the header to `"application/json"`.
And it uses a [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to send network requests and receive replies.

```
QUrl url("https://api.github.com/repos/" + owner +"/" + project + "/tags");
qInfo() << url.toString();
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
QNetworkAccessManager nam;
QNetworkReply * reply = nam.get(request);
```